# What type of cloud is this?

Tags: meteorology, clouds

I live in a sub-tropical region of Australia.

Earlier today, we experienced temperatures of 31C and it was clear about 2 hours before I went out and noticed the following clouds directly above my house - the entire sky either has this or is very grey.

There is a constant background of thunder and distant lightning is observed - the wind is picking up a bit, though still a breeze. No rain at this stage.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are [mammatus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammatus_cloud) clouds. The signify instability (via negative buoyancy, convective mixing, entrainment or other sources) at the cloud base which causes the bulbous udder-like structure. As in your case they can often be observed in association with strong convection.

Comment: The sky is getting very dark now - I suspected that they were mammatus - thank you for that!

Comment: Just to confirm that it is mammatus. Such cloud formations generally don't last for long because of the inherent instability of their formation. Nice photo, by the way.